# making a jquery slider being responsive for finger slide on tablet

Tags: jquery, tablet, nivo-slider

I am currently using nivo slider and I was wondering if anyone know if there is a possibility to make it slide on finger move. If not, maybe someone knows any sliders that will work that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a jQuery for iOS to listen to touch gestures maybe integrating these would be able to give you this functionality.